# Android SQLite Insert Performance

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, insert

I might just be hitting native performance issues with SQLite, but there seems to be significant overhead associated with inserting in SQLite even using Transaction processing and pre-compiled statements. Or perhaps I am using them incorrectly.

I have a requirement to read a file line by line (via a URL) and create rows. The mechanism is generic, so any table can be created (within reason) and any number of rows added. I am seeing pretty decent performance for larger inserts, but with smaller ones it seems I have a minimum of +400ms. Since I may have over 100 of these to load, that small overhead is resulting in large load times.

For example some timings:

```
   34 records Test #1  ---->  490 ms
36238 records Test #2  ----> 3021 ms
    4 records Test #3  ---->  520 ms
```

Here is the code (I cut out all the try/catches and other code to boil it down to the actual insert code):

```
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

        // Create the file reader
        BufferedReader  br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuffer insertSql = null;

        // Build the SQL to bind
        insertSql = new StringBuffer("INSERT INTO " + fileName + " (");
        String sep = "";
        insertSql.append("[" + getDbColumnNames().replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll(",", "],[") + "]");
        String[] columns = getDbColumnNames().split(",");
        insertSql.append(") VALUES (");
        for (@SuppressWarnings("unused") String col : columns) {
            insertSql.append(sep.trim() + "?");
            sep = ",";
        }
        insertSql.append(");");
        this.open();
        sqlDB.beginTransaction();
        SQLiteStatement stmt = = sqlDB.compileStatement(insertSql.toString());

        String line = "";
        // Read the file line by line
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");
            // Build the bindings and insert the data
            int bindcnt = 1;
            for (String token : tokens) {
                 stmt.bindString(bindcnt++, token.trim());
            }

            long entryID = stmt.executeInsert();
            if (entryID < 0) {
                success = false;
            }
            stmt.clearBindings();
        }
        sqlDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
        sqlDB.endTransaction();
```

I have verified that the read buffer overhead is not significant for most of the reads.

Comment: A smaller number of inserts will have a relatively similar fixed overhead (writing to the disk) as a large number on inserts. Can't you combine the smaller ones into a larger (or a number of larger) inserts (transaction wise)?

Comment: @MikeT Unfortunately not. They are architected to be in their own table. So bottom line is that there is a 300ms overhead for small inserts, no matter what?